# Need help to remove empty lists from dictionaries

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
    a_dict = {1: "hello", 2: [], 3: [], 4: "hey", 5:"phone"}
```

And I want to remove all the empty lists from this dictionary.

```
    Output: a_dict = {1:"hello",4:"hey",5:"phone"}
```

I tried this:

```
    for item in a_dict:
        if a_dict[item] == []:
            del item
```

However, this just gives back the original dictionary. It doesn't do anything to it.

Comment: `del a_dict[item]`

Comment: @Barmar `"dict size changed during iteration"` ?

Comment: `a_dict = {k:v for k,v in a_dict.items() if v}`

Comment: `for item in list(a_dict):` to make a copy.

Comment: @DeepSpace There are hundreds of questions about that error message, did you make any attempt to look it up?

Comment: @Barmar I was pointing out that your suggested solution would cause that error, which obviously OP will ask about

Comment: @DeepSpace Oops, I assumed you were the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be deleting key of a dict while you are iterating it. You can save your keys in some other variable and use it to delete keys. Here is a solution very much similar to your current code.

```
deleteKeys = []

for item in a_dict:
        if a_dict[item] == []:
            deleteKeys.append(item)

for i in deleteKeys:
    del a_dict[i]
```